# Saving multiple input fields using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to save values of input fields on the fly using ajax. I'm using the Laravel framework to craft my applications.
Below is the code I'm using to create the fields. The problem is that the name of the input field is the same on every table row, so when submitting the form using ajax, only the value on the first row gets pushed. Could someone point me in the right direction of how to solve this. Should I give the input fields unique names? And if so, how can I retrieve these values in my controller?

```
@if($orsrg->aant_gelev = 1)
  <tr id="{{ $orderregel->regel }}">
     <td>{{ $orsrg->artcode }}</td>
     <td>{{ $orsrg->oms45 }}</td>
     <td>
         <form class='addtagform' method='post'>
           <input type="hidden" name="_token" id="token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
           <input type='hidden' name='ordernr[]' value='{{ $orkrg->ordernr }}'>
           <input type='hidden' name='regel[]' value='{{ $orsrg->regel }}'>
           <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type='text' id="tag" name="tag" class='form-control' maxlength='24' value="{{ $orderregel->tags()->pluck('tag')->first() }}"></form></td>
  </tr> 
@endif
```

The ajax / jquery I'm using is as follows (it saves the value to the database 1 second after a change is made):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeoutId;
    $('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function () {
        console.log('Textarea Change');
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            saveToDB();
        }, 1000);
    });
    function saveToDB()
    {
        console.log('Saving to the db');
        form = $('.addtagform');
        var tag = $('input[name=tag]', this.form).val();
        var ordernr = $('input[name=ordernr]', this.form).val();
        var regel = $('input[name=regel]', this.form).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/warehouse/tag",
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            type: "POST",
            data: {tag: tag, ordernr: ordernr, regel: regel},
            success: function (data) {
                var jqObj = jQuery(data);

                var d = new Date();
                $('.form-status-holder').html('Saved! Last: ' + d.toLocaleTimeString());
            },
        });
    }

    $('.addtagform').submit(function (e) {
        saveToDB();
        e.preventDefault();
        s
    });
});
```

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ - let jQuery serialise your form instead of pulling out all the fields manually

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try and let you know the results!

Comment: @ADyson Thanks a lot for your advise. That did the trick. I can't seem to find how to upvote your comment or mark it as an answer to my question, but it definitely was! Thanks for your effort!

Comment: That's because it was done as a comment not an answer. I'll add it as an answer below shortly, then you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler and easier approach to your requirement would be to use jQuery's `serialize()` function - you call that on your form and it will automatically get all the form data into the encoded format required for sending to the server. e.g.

```
data: form.serialize()
```

See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for more details.